# Dial using second sim card (j2me)

Tags: java, java-me, telephony

For dual sim phones, such as samsung D780, is there a way to dial a number using second sim card.

What I currently use is

```
platformRequest("tel:+1201xxxxxx");
```

I have tried playing with `;tsp=` but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using AT commands for the same , may be ATD 9999999999 would help , look for complete help on AT Commands. AT Commands are simple ATTENTION commands that are issued to SIM either by MODEM/PHONE inorder to make sim perform some actions.